# Inability to set value of public class field from constructor of super if that field is redefined in the inheriting class

Tags: javascript

I use polymorphism with JSDoc to describe concrete implementations of some classes. Up until now I have been doing this with getters and setters; newly implemented [public class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields#public_instance_fields) can shorten this getter and setter boilerplate considerably.

My problem is described by the code snippet below. The value set in the constructor does not survive the redefining of the public class field. How can I redefine a public class field in an inheriting class and keep the value set in the super constructor? Is this a bug in public class fields?

```js
class ThingHolder {
  /**@type {notKnownYet}*/
  publicFieldForThing
  constructor(thing) {
    this.publicFieldForThing = thing
    //Do stuff for all thing holders
  }
  dropMyThing() {
    //Throw not implemented
  }
  setThingField(thing) {
    this.publicFieldForThing = thing
  }
}

class RedThingHolder extends ThingHolder {
  /**@type {RedThing}*/
  publicFieldForThing
  dropMyThing() {
    //functionality for dropping a red thing with JSDoc niceties for RedThings
  }
}
class BlueThingHolder extends ThingHolder {
  /**@type {BlueThing}*/
  publicFieldForThing
  dropMyThing() {
    //functionality for dropping a blue thing with JSDoc niceties for BlueThings
  }
}

const redThing = {
  colour: "red"
}

//Setting the thing in the constructor results in unextected behaviour
const redThingHolder = new RedThingHolder(redThing)
console.assert(redThingHolder.publicFieldForThing === redThing)

//Setting the thing through an inherited method after construction works perfectly fine
redThingHolder.setThingField(redThing)
console.assert(redThingHolder.publicFieldForThing === redThing)
```

Edit: This question was not about my motivations. Why do public fields behave differently to getters with regard to the prototype chain?

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    console.log("prop in instance during super: ", "prop" in this)
    console.log("publicField in instance during super: ", "publicField" in this)
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super()
    console.log("prop in instance after super: ", "prop" in this)
    console.log("publicField in instance after super: ", "publicField" in this)
  }
  publicField
  get prop() { }
}

new Child
```

Comment: Why do you need to re-define the property in the child classes?

Comment: There are a couple of reasons but the reason that matters the most is commented above; the developer experience when passing a well documented class onto other members of a team. Red things and blue things all have very different properties and methods.

Comment: You call it improving DX, I'd say you're violating DRY. If you don't want to utilize inheritance, don't use inheritance. Just offer all shared implementation as standalone functions or something?

Comment: _"the developer experience"_ -  i am not sure how re-defining a field improves the developer experience instead of confusing them.

Comment: Its a simple question but you want to argue motives. Have you used typescript before? For smaller micro libraries we do not use typescript in favour of interface styled classes with JSDoc definitions for different concrete types. It is a shame that this has confused you.

Comment: Just trying to help buddy.

Comment: You're not helping buddy. I've edited the question.

Comment: See the edit at the end of the answer.

Comment: Thankyou for that

Answer (score 1):

When you call the constructor of `RedThingHolder` class

```
new RedThingHolder(redThing)
```

the default constructor of `RedThingHolder` will pass the parameter `redThing` to the super class' constructor which will add a property `publicFieldForThing` on the newly created object.

Re-definition of `publicFieldForThing` in child classes *overwrites* the `publicFieldForThing` set inside the super class.

> I feel like this is a bug and that the value should be retained
> automatically.

Its not a bug and redefining a property with the same name will not *retain* a value because you are defining a field with a name that already exists on an object. Instead of *retaining*, it will overwrite the existing field.

Doing this

```
class RedThingHolder {
   publicFieldForThing;
   ...
}
```

will overwrite the `publicFieldForThing` field with the default value of `undefined`.

> How can I redefine a public class field in an inheriting class and
> keep the value set in the super constructor?

You can set the `publicFieldForThing` in the child class constructor using the getter for `publicFieldForThing` defined in the super class.

```js
class ThingHolder {
  constructor(thing) {
    this.publicFieldForThing = thing;
  }

  get publicField() {
    return this.publicFieldForThing;
  }
}

class RedThingHolder extends ThingHolder {
  constructor(thing) {
   super(thing);
   this.publicFieldForThing = this.publicField;
  }
}

const redThing = {
  colour: 'red',
};

const redThingHolder = new RedThingHolder(redThing);
console.log(redThingHolder.publicFieldForThing === redThing);
```

#### Edit

> Why do public fields behave differently to getters with regard to the
> prototype chain?

getter/setters in ES2015's classes are added on the proptotype object whereas the public fields are added on the object itself.

In the code example you posted, `prop` is added on the `Child.prototype` whereas the `publicField` is like doing

```
this.publicField = undefined;
```

in the constructor of the `Child` class just *after* the `super()` call.

This is why `"prop" in this` inside the constructor of the `Parent` class returns `true` whereas `"publicField" in this` evaluates to `true` only inside the constructor of the `Child` class.

Comment: You removed the JSDoc typing in on the redefined field which defeats the whole purpose for the question

Comment: I disagree, had it been a getter and setter that were redefined in the child class, setting the property in the constructor would actually call the redefined setter.

Comment: "this" in the super constructor is an instance of the child

Comment: _"this" in the super constructor is an instance of the child_ - correct. Let me re-phrase my last comment which i have deleted. Constructor in super class will set `publicFieldForThing` on the newly created instance. After super class constructor has executed, an object has been created and initialized. In the child class, redefining the field will not _retain_ the value - instead it will hide/override the already added field in the super class.